# CSS two clickable elements show different content

Tags: html, css, duplicates, show

I need help with a little css.

I have two clickable text areas (like in the code pen below). If i click the first one the first text and img need to be shown and if i click the second textfield the second text and img need to be show.

I didn't get it. I´m too stupid.

I prefer css only. If there is no other way JS is also possible.

```css
.test{
  float:left;
  background-color: gray; /*only when active*/
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
.text1{
display:block;
  background-color:gray;
}
.text2{
  display: none;
      background-color:gray;

}
.img1 img{
max-width: 600px;}
.img2 img{
max-width: 600px;
display: none}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="img1"><img src="https://smartphone-klinik.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/K1600_pexels-photo-572688.jpg"></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="https://smartphone-klinik.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pexels-photo-534736.jpeg"></div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <p class="test">Click Area 1</p>
    <p class="test">Click Area 2</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  </p> 
<p class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: and what did you tried ? there is nothing related to clicks in your code ... and since you are using Bootstrap consider tabs then

Comment: Use [**bootstrap tabs**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs)...

Answer (score 0):

This should be the behavior you want:

Using bootstrap tab:

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/ewhnv0ua/

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Click Area 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Click Area 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="img1">
            <img src="https://smartphone-klinik.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/K1600_pexels-photo-572688.jpg">
        </div>
        <p class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p> 
    </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="img2">
        <img src="https://smartphone-klinik.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pexels-photo-534736.jpeg">
      </div>
      <p class="text1">
        aLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </p>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is an idea to do it using pure css.
you can change the position with help of media queries.

```css
.test{
  float:left;
  background-color: gray; /*only when active*/
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
.text1{
display:block;
  background-color:gray;
}
.text2{
  display: none;
      background-color:yellow;

}
.img1 img{
max-width: 600px;}
.img2 img{
max-width: 600px;
display: none}

.relative{
  position:relative;
}
.tabContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left:0;
}
a.test:focus + p.tabContent{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
   
 

<div class=" relative">
    <a href="#" class="test">Click Area 1</a>
    <p class="text1 tabContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  </p> 
    <a href="#" class="test">Click Area 2</a>
    <p class="text2 tabContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
</p>
</div>
```